# tcl Split Directory year string

Tags: tcl

I have various possibilities a dirnames.

Example:

```
USA.LA.2017-02-02
EU.2016-04-04
EU.FR.Paris.2014-05-05
CA.Que.Ed.Cal.2013-04-04
```

I need a new variable with Example:

```
USA.LA
EU
EU FR Paris
CA Que Ed Cal
```

Unfortunately it is not always right in my tcl.

```
set foo [join [lrange [split $name .] 0 1] .]
set replaced_relname [string map {. " "} $foo]
```

Does anyone have a different idea?

Comment: If you really need the `.` between the `USA` and the `LA` in the output, that'll require a special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lrange` to drop only the last element

```
set dirnames { USA.LA.2017-02-02  EU.2016-04-04  EU.FR.Paris.2014-05-05  CA.Que.Ed.Cal.2013-04-04 }

foreach dirname $dirnames {
    set string [join [lrange [split $dirname .] 0 end-1]]
    puts $string
}
```

```
USA LA
EU
EU FR Paris
CA Que Ed Cal
```